# Where can I farm Titanite Chunks?

Tags: dark-souls-2

Where can you farm Titanite Chunks in Dark Souls II?

Titanite Chunks can ascend +7 weapons to +9. There do not seem to be any chunks accessible early in the game, where can I farm this item?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a little late in the game, but the **Black Gulch** is a good area to farm titanite chunks and large titanite pieces. The best part is, there is close to zero risk of you dying from this, once you get the hang of it.

Shoot the black tar pits with a **fire arrow**, and the creatures will die from fire. When they are dead, run up, collect items, and repeat. Use a **bonfire Ascetic** at the first bonfire, to get the mobs to respawn. You can shoot at the tar pits a little after the first bonfire. If you use a **bonfire Ascetic** at the second bonfire, the boss will respawn, but not the mobs.

To farm the second area, stand at the exit of the second bonfire, and you can ignite the 5-6 tar pits quickly and easily. Best part is, when you replay it in NG + later games, this will not make the area significantly harder, because you can use the same cheesy tactic, to take out the mobs, without danger to yourself.

This will also net you quite a lot of souls. Remember to equip the **Jester's cap**: http://darksouls2.wikidot.com/jester-s-cap + **Covetous Gold Serpent Ring**: http://darksouls2.wikidot.com/covetous-gold-serpent-ring

Answer (score 11):

Join the Princess Bell Covenant, and wear the ring the little guy gives you. Beat the invaders and you will get a chunk *every time* you succeed.

It was the first covenant I joined. It was really fun and I now have 50 chucks because of it

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure the drop rate, but if you don't want to join a covenant, I managed to get a chunk off one of the dwarfs in Gyrm's Respite.

If i remember correctly it was the Shield Type.

Comment: On a side note the little gnome dwarfs carrying anvils in that area drop large titanite shards, i used 2 pharros stones to open some passage ways and got empty rooms with those little guys inside (game cheated me -_-). Conformation on the chunks btw i got another from the shield dwarfs.

Comment: You can just buy them from the merchants (not saying who because of spoiler issues) later on in the game. Unlimited supply!

Answer (score 1):

In Brightstone Cove Tseldora, you can farm the peasant farmers for titanite shards/chunks. Better drop rate than dark wraiths in DS1 too, haha

Answer (score 1):

Use the bonfire ascetic in cardinal tower,in the room with 4 big crossbow pointing at you,below is a chest that will contain 3 titanite chunk,if you wish to repeat you must defeat the giant and the pursuer again..

Comment: defeat as in, in NG+?

Comment: Nope they will spawn as soon as you use bonfire ascetic,so it's good for farming souls too

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about early game, but if you beat the game, you can buy infinite from stone trader Chloanne.

Comment: I think this answer is still useful to help someone plan their Titanite Chunks. Right before going into NG+, buy all the Chunks you think you'll need and you're golden.